# How can I use `M-x` in `emacs -nw` in zshell

Tags: macos, emacs, zsh

It is my first time to use `emacs -nw`. But I have problem at the first when I type `M-x`. In the minibuffer, it shows "Mark set" instead of `M-x`
I don't know why it happens. How can I deal with it?

PS: My os is Macosx and I connect remote by using `ssh` and then I type `emacs -nw` but I cannot use `M-x`

Update:08/30/2015

When I see the options under `M-x customize-group ns`, it seems that `Alt` is actually used as Meta? Why it didn’t works.

14Hide Ns Alternate Modifier: [Value Menu] meta                                                                                 |
15   [ State ]: STANDARD.                                                                                                       |
16   This variable describes the behavior of the alternate or option key. More                                                  |

37Hide Ns Right Alternate Modifier: [Value Menu] Use the value of ns-alternate-modifier                                         |
38   [ State ]: STANDARD.                                                                                                       |
39   This variable describes the behavior of the right alternate or option key. More                                            |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Emacs in the terminal (switch `-nw`), you might not have a `Meta` key, depending on your platform etc.  In particular, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> keyboard key might not function as the `Meta` key.  You might find some information (e.g. here, or by googling) about how to get it working as `Meta` for your context (platform etc.), but you might not.

You can always use `ESC` (the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key) followed by a key to act the same as the `Meta` modifier applied to that key.  For example, instead of `M-x`, you can use `ESC x`.

(You press and release `ESC`, and then do the same for `x`. `ESC` is not a modifier key -- you do not hold it pressed while hitting `x`.)

Comment: Thank you for the `ESC`, it is for emergencies. I still want to use 'Alt'.
When I see the options under `M-x customize-group ns`, it seems that `Alt` is actually used as Meta? Why it didn’t works.

14Hide Ns Alternate Modifier: [Value Menu] meta                                                                                 |             

37Hide Ns Right Alternate Modifier: [Value Menu] Use the value of ns-alternate-modifier                                         |

Comment: As I suggested, it might be that `Alt-x` (or `Alt` generally) is grabbed by your platform and Emacs never sees it. What happens when you do `C-h k Alt-x`? My guess is that Emacs does not even recognize the use of `Alt`. Just a guess. If so, then you might need to check the doc for your platform, to see if you can stop it from grabbing `Alt`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that OSX is stealing the key. There are a few things which will make your life easier

1. Install emacs using homebrew. The version which comes with OSX is old
2. Use iterm2 instead of the default term.app - much better and feature rich
3. In iterm2, you can set a key override for either the left or right option as +ESC, which will make it all work.

This will all work on a local machine, but you may run into additional problems if your connecting to a remote machine and running emacs there. It is a similar problem, your key settings may no be getting stolen/dropped by the ssh session - all depends on your terminal, your ssh config and the remote system.

Note that with emacs, you often don't need to run remote. Emacs comes with a built-in system called Tramp, which is very powerful. Using tramp, you can open remote directories and edit the files as if they were local files. You run emacs locally and tramp uses ssh to open the remote files, read the contents into the local emacs buffer and then write the changes back tot he remote file. Helps to have ssh keys setup so you don't have to worry about passwords (but you will need an ssh-agent to make this work easily).

In general, when you find emads does not respond to a key press, especailly if you try C-h k and nothing happens when you hit the key bindings you can't get to work, it is almost certain that something in-between you and emacs is stealing the keys - this is often the window manager or OS, but it can also be due to terminal emulators etc. In over 20 years of using emacs, I've never had emacs 'do nothing' when you hit a key combination - if emacs recieves the key input, it will respond with something, even if that something is to tell you there is no key binding for the keys you pressed. If emacs does absolutely nothing, you know the message just isn't get through!

Comment: Thank you for your advice, the reason I don't want to use  Tramp is that I need to type `C-x C-f /remotehost:filename  RET` every time when I want to open and edit files. Often this is not fast. Also, a good suggestion to use ·item2· :-D

Comment: FYI - You do not need to type that each time, for files or directories that you want to visit often. Just use Emacs **bookmarks** to your remote files or dirs. For example, have a bookmark to a remote directory (Dired buffer) where you work a lot.

Comment: @Drew Great. Bookmarks is a good idea. And it is also helpful for the local directory. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Open Terminal Preferences
2. Select Profiles
3. Keyboard
4. Check the box for "Use Option as Meta Key"